# SuiteScript. How to retrieve primary contacts from customer record. if the type is company

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

When I am choosing the customer (type: Individual) First and Last name retrieves into the same fields [see 1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGfaw.png), but it doesn't work with type: company. So I created a primary contact in Customer record and want the code retrieve primary contact.[see 2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9pQa.png). How do I can retrieve first and last name if I choose customer with type: company. like in the 1st screenshot.

```
    if (scriptContext.fieldId === 'custrecord_cc_customer'){
    var value = objRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord_cc_customer'
    });

    var fieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
        type: search.Type.CUSTOMER, 
        id: value, // Customer ID from customer field
        columns: ['firstname', 'lastname']
    });

    objRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord_cc_firstname',
        value: fieldLookUp.firstname,

    });

    objRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custrecord_cc_lastname',
        value: fieldLookUp.lastname,
    });

    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, contacts is sublist on customer record so you need to use getSublistText or getCurrentSublistText if you are working on record object, where sublistId is **contactroles** and fieldId is **contact**.

If you have a search object, you have to add search column with join where column name is **entityid** and join is **contact**.

So, your `search.lookupfields` should have a **contact.entityid** in a search column.